# Laravel: Register is submitting null value for Username even when filled

Tags: php, laravel, faker, laravel-8, laravel-ui

When registering a new user, I want them to pick a unique username. Everything worked with the username when I used Jetstream but when I rebuilt with Laravel Fortify and Laravel UI, the username is null regardless of what the user enters in the field. Below I have included several samples of code used to add and register the username.

I am not getting any errors in debugging or in the logs to support any known issues.

Register.blade.php (Username Input)

```
<div class="px-2">
     <x-general.form.label for="username" label="{{ __('Username') }}" class="" />
     <x-general.form.input type="text" name="username" class="@error('username') is-invalid @enderror" value="" />

     @error('username')
     <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
     </span>
     @enderror
</div>
```

App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php (create function)

```
public function create(array $input)
{
    Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:16'],
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'email',
            'max:255',
            Rule::unique(User::class),
        ],
        'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
    ])->validate();

    return User::create([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'username' => $input['username'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
    ]);
}
```

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'username',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Create Users Table Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

UserFactory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'username' => $this->faker->unique()->userName,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];


            print_r($this->faker->unique()->userName);
            exit;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why the username isn't being submitted.
This is all the same code as I used in my Jetstream based project.

Any help is wonderful and appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your User Model (fully) it looks like you have a copy paste fail

Comment: @ballard I updated it above.

Comment: The reason I first asked for your User.php Model is because `fillable` usually catches everyone out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `$this->faker->unique()->userName,` you are missing capitalization there on `userName`.

See both:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerprovideren_usperson

extract: `userName // 'wade55'`

Comment: I changed that and now I have this ```SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value```

Comment: do a `print_r($this->faker->unique()->userName); exit;` in `public function definition()`

Comment: alternatively add `->nullable` to your migration temporarily on username to see what/if the column is populated

Comment: That let the form submit but the value is still null https://gyazo.com/e4175d5b0e00c1a9185061ffade39d9d

Comment: I'd drop the table and migrate it again

Comment: try to change `config/database.php` and set `'strict' => false`

Comment: It's still not working... I'm wondering if it's an issue with a vendor but there isn't any easy way to find out because im not seeing any errors.. At this point im wondering if i should rebuild. @ballard

Comment: Updated the UserFactory snippet. @ballard

Comment: put that `print_r` before your return

Comment: It didn't output anything which makes me believe its an issue with the field/form somehow

Comment: I'm out of suggestions, but at least I could help iron out some of the other bugs

Comment: thank you @ballard for of the help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I figured it out! There was a secondary controller for Register once I added Laravel UI that didn't have the username field added to it. Once that was fixed, it all works. I feel so stupid.

Comment: oh damn, grats on finding the issue!